Smooth Structures on $\mathbb{R}$
I am reading through Lee's Smooth Manifold textbook and in the book he introduces smooth structures on manifolds as a maximal atlas on the manifold where the transition maps are smooth in the usual sense.
In one of the examples he gives he says that the homeomorphism $x^3:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ induces smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ that is different than the usual one. What I was wondering about is that if I have another smooth homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (say something like $f(x) = x^7$ this is smooth but not smooth at the origin) does this also define a smooth structure? Does every smooth homeomorphism determine a smooth structure?
Thank you for the help.

Each homeomorphism $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ gives the atlas $\mathcal A(h) = \{ h\}$ on $\mathbb R$. This atlas is trivially smooth because it has no non-trivial transition functions (the only transition functions are $h^{-1} \circ h = h  \circ h^{-1} = id$).
What is the relation between the smooth structure generated by $\mathcal A(h)$ and the standard smooth structure generated by $\mathcal S = \{ id\}$?
In order that these smooth strucures coincide the transition functions
$h \circ id^{-1} = h$ and $id \circ h^{-1} = h^{-1}$ have to be smooth. This means that $h$ has to be a diffeomorphism.
Smooth homeomorphisms are in general no diffeomorphisms. As examples take the functions $h_n(x) = x^{2n+1}$ with $n \ge 1$. Their inverses are not differentiable at $x = 0$.
Given a homeomorphism $h$, let $\mathbb R _h$ denote the smooth manifold with smooth structure generated by $\mathcal A(h)$. Although in general $\mathbb R \ne \mathbb R_h$ as smooth manifolds, $h : \mathbb R _h \to \mathbb R$ is always a diffeomorphism.
To see this, simply observe $id \circ h \circ h^{-1} = id$ and $h \circ h^{-1} \circ id = id$ are smooth.
